# Unable to create new Company for Developer Story

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/create
2. Fill in information and click Next
3. In the Company field I fill in "MyCompany", which doesn't exist yet
4. I click on 'Use "MyCompany"'
5. Nothing happens

I tried this with Firefox 50.1.0 and Safari 10.0.2 on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your report. That was a client side issue, apparently we forgot to hide the company suggestion list when a non existent company is added. The issue has been fixed and should be up with our next prod build.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know when this build will be deployed? I'd be happy to confirm the bug to be fixed.

Comment: @WimMostrey should be good now :)

Comment: That bug is fixed, but it added a new one. After selecting `'Use "MyCompany"'` I went back to the previous form to add some more tags to `Tech you want to work with` and when I select "Next" nothing happens. I logged out and back in again and I simply can't get past the initial form. Tried with my other browser (Safari 10.0.2) and nothing happens when I select "Next". Shall I open a new bug issue for this?

Comment: @WimMostrey hm, yes please. I'll take a look at it right now.

Comment: I opened a new [bug report](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341210/unable-to-access-second-form-to-create-a-developer-story).