# Unable to access second form to create a Developer Story

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

This bug report is a follow-up on the now-fixed bug [Unable to create new Company for Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341117/unable-to-create-new-company-for-developer-story/341201). I'm using OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 with Firefox 50.1.0.

This bug report involves three steps. Steps to reproduce:

### Step 1

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/create
2. Fill in information and click Next
3. In the Company field I fill in "MyCompany", which doesn't exist yet
4. I click on 'Use "MyCompany"'
5. It works. Previously mentioned bug: fixed.

### Step 2

6. After clicking on 'Use "MyCompany"' I go back to the previous form to add more tags to the `Tech you want to work with` field.
7. I click Next.
8. Nothing happens, the "Next" button keeps throbbing.

[image: Throbber, nothing happens.]

### Step 3

Trying to resolve this, I log out and back in again. I click "Next" but still nothing happens. I open Safari 10.0.2, log in and go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/create. I click "Next" and nothing happens.

Comment: We just went through ~20min of downtime on some of the features around Jobs and Developer Stories due to some heavy cleanup that went wrong. The wizard was one of the affected parts, unfortunately. I just created a new account and went through the steps, and it all worked fine. Could you try again please and let me know if it's still broken on your end?

Comment: Fixed, as per [rla4's comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341210/unable-to-access-second-form-to-create-a-developer-story?noredirect=1#comment430343_341210). Thanks!